# Passing a function in an anchor within a console vb.net

Tags: vb.net

please how can i pass a link with function which take an id from a function please

```
 Dim Email As String = "ultimadan@hotmail.com"
    Dim msgBody As New StringBuilder()
    msgBody.Append("Thank you, please click the link below.")

    msgBody.Append("<a href=http://localhost:49789/Seller/Part1/Default.aspx?" & GetUserID(Email))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're just not building the complete anchor tag.  You're missing a key for the query string value, you're not closing the tag, etc.  Your current code might produce something like:

```
<a href=http://localhost:49789/Seller/Part1/Default.aspx?123
```

Which isn't complete or valid HTML.  Did you mean something more like this?:

```
msgBody.Append(
  "<a href=""http://localhost:49789/Seller/Part1/Default.aspx?userid="
  & GetUserID(Email)
  & """>click here</a>"
)
```

Which should produce something more like:

```
<a href="http://localhost:49789/Seller/Part1/Default.aspx?userid=123">click here</a>
```

Comment: yes but there is this problem now Error 1 'click' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level.

Comment: @user3246292: That error doesn't make a whole lot of sense given the code in the question.  What's actually throwing that error?  Can you update your question with more information?

Comment: so i'm doing a console that send an email to a user with a link, this link will contain the function getuserid which pass an email to a website on my localhost

Comment: the click here don't appear as link :(

Comment: @user3246292: Is the email in HTML format?  Can you be more specific about the problem?  You're asking a number of things that are all outside the scope of the original question and unrelated to the code posted.

Comment: yes i put  e_mail.IsBodyHtml = True, but the problem here is that the click here don't appear as a link, the code is a console application in vb.net, the code should procedure something like this <a href="http://localhost:49789/Seller/Part1/Default.aspx?userid=123">click here</a> like you say

Comment: sorry it was that pass an id not an email sorry